# Why the strange duplication in Javascript instance objects?

Tags: javascript

While using Javascript for some fun, I ran into a morass of difficulties surrounding classes and objects. I thought I got that it is not Java, nor c++. Finally, I took my problems into a smallish example to study this.

Running the example produces output:

```
>>>>>> keys aprop,bprep,cprep,dprop,bprop,cprop.
```

I expected output:

```
>>>>>> keys aprop,bprep,cprep,dprop.
```

If duplication, why are not aprop and dprop also duplicated? I had thought that by using *getOwnPropertyNames* I prevented prototype keys. Is there a way to fix this short of comparing each key to eliminate duplicates?

```
<script>

var objList = [];


class TestObj {
    constructor(aprop, bprop, cprop) {
        this.aprop = aprop;
        this.bprep = bprop;
        this.cprep = cprop;
        this.dprop = 0;
    }
    getAprop() { return aprop; }
    getBprop() { return bprop; }
    getCprop() { return cprop; }
    getDprop() { return dprop; }

    setAprop(arg) { aprop = arg; }
    setBprop(arg) { bprop = arg; }
    setCprop(arg) { cprop = arg; }
    setDprop(arg) { dprop = arg; }
}

function create() {
    putList();
    var t1 = objList[1];
    alert("fromlist "+t1);

    var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(t1);
    console.log(">>>>>> keys "+keys);
}

function putList() {    
    onlist(1, "one" [1]);
    onlist(2, "two", [2, 2]);
    onlist(3, "three", [3, 3, 3]);
}
function onlist(a, b, c) {
    var item = new TestObj();
    item.aprop = a;
    item.bprop = b;
    item.cprop = c;
    objList.push(item);
}


create();

</script>
```

Comment: It might help to make your example more minimal; you create a bunch of objects, but only one of them is used, and the getters and setters aren’t necessary and don’t actually work. Maybe reduce it to `function TestObj() { this.aprop = 0; } var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new TestObj()); console.log(keys);`?

Comment: And where do you set `Testobj.prototype.somekey` ?

Comment: There is no duplication. You simply misspelled some of the preperty names.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is actually your question. Anyway, here goes:

First, a minimal example:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = 0;
}

Object.keys(new Foo)
```

The result of this expression is `["bar"]` instead of `[]` because setting properties in a constructor is no different from setting them anywhere else. They’re not on the prototype just by virtue of being in a constructor. This would work:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 0;

Object.keys(new Foo)
```

Now `bar` is on the prototype, and `Object.keys`, which only lists own property names, returns `[]` for a `Foo` instance. This isn’t usually what you want, though; assigning to `bar` on an instance will still create a new own property, and if it were mutable, then mutating it would affect all instances of `Foo`.

> Is there a way to fix this short of comparing each key to eliminate duplicates?

Don’t loop over properties in the first place.

… and on the off-chance you really mean “duplicates”, note that you spelled them differently: “bpr**e**p” and “cpr**e**p” vs. “bpr**o**p” and “cpr**o**p”.